# Read attached cameras and microphones names of a system through c# code

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to develop an **winform app which reads attached cameras and microphones names from the system** and displays it with radioboxes so that the user can select an attached microphone and camera and proceed to the next form where video conference happens....!!

But, I am not able to read attached hardware names of the system..Please suggest some way..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an article on CodeProject that might help - [Retrieving Hardware Information in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7365/Retrieving-Hardware-Information-in-C):

> This article will explain how to use WMI to access hardware information and properties. It will not set properties of hardware, only retrieve information about it.

WMI refers to [Windows Management Instrumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx), and the majority of the code will use the [`System.Management`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) namespace.

This sample I wrote will display a list of sound devices on your PC:

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Management.Instrumentation;

namespace Test {
    class TestClass {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Win32 SoundDevices\r\n===============================");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_SoundDevice");
            foreach (ManagementObject soundDevice in searcher.Get()) {
                Console.WriteLine("Device found: {0}\n", soundDevice.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Search complete.");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

You'll want to look at [WMI Query Samples](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/wmi/samples/) to help you figure out how to find the devices you're looking to identify. Microsoft also has a [WMI Code Creator utility](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) that might help:

> The WMI Code Creator tool allows you to generate VBScript, C#, and VB .NET code that uses WMI to complete a management task such as querying for management data, executing a method from a WMI class, or receiving event notifications using WMI.

Comment: Thanks for such descriptive answer Jared..!!